# How to query " WHERE call.tags ? '1' " in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have JSONB filed tags in postgres with list inside.

```
e=# SELECT tags FROM call WHERE call.tags ? '1';
    tags
------------
 ["1", "2"]
 ["1"]
(2 rows)
```

(for this query i have index in postgres).

How to express same filter condition in sqlalchemy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use raw sql in filter

```
from sqlalchemy import text

db.session.query(Call).filter(text("tags ? '1'")
```